# solar putty - post-authentication script

Tags: shell, networking, ssh, admin

I'm trying to login to a Cisco device as the following example:

Credentials:
username: cisco
password: cisco

Then, I want a post-authentication script to say:
enable
password1

Does anyone know what sort of script I should make, and what format I should save that script in too? The documentation doesn't mention a whole lot

https://thwack.solarwinds.com/docs/DOC-202262#start=100